# UIButton is not receive touch events

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton that is not receiving touch events. I think their might be a transparent view in the way. How can I detect what is being touched?

I think their is an app that allows me to turn my UI sideways while in the simulator, but i cannot remember the name of it. I would be willing to buy it.

Or is there a way to do this code?

Comment: The app you are looking for is [RevealApp](http://revealapp.com/)

Comment: if you think a transparent view covers the button, then simply you can check it in simulator while running app. go to Debug-> Color Blended Layers. then you can seen different layer on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that Allow User Interaction is checked.

You could also delete the button, drag it back onto your view and hook up the methods.

Also make sure you are connected to the Touch Up Inside event and your method is an IBOutlet

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

Comment: I think you meant `IBAction`, not `IBOutlet`... I've submitted an edit.

Comment: Late night typo, yes that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Allow user interaction like this:

```
yourButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

And if you add your button is on top of a `UIImageView`, then add  this:  `yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I did not set the width and height for autolayout so even though I saw the view, its height and width were 0,0.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on  [DCIntrospect](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect)
. It might solve your problem in. It's free to use and open source.